# mongoose return json list of tags specified as subdocuments

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

so i am having this problem that keeps me busy for the past 4 days, i am having a schema and subdocument schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    category: String,
    description: String,
    tags: [TagSchema]
});

var TagSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    date: Date
});

mongoose.model( 'TagSchema', TagSchema );
mongoose.model( 'Project', Project );
```

and what i want to have is a list of all tags of all ProjectSchemas, whatever i try i either get NONE or just the ones of the most current Project. i just dont know further because whatever i do i always end up failing on this one. what am i doing wrong, is there no such thing as a findAll for mongoose?

```
app.get('/tags.json', function(req, res) {
    TagSchema.find({}, function ( err, tags ){
        var json = JSON.stringify(tags);
        console.log(json);
    tags = tags.map(function (tag) {
        return tag.toObject();
    });
    console.log(json == JSON.stringify(tags));
    res.json(json);
    });
});
```

and

```
app.get('/tags.json', function(req, res) {
    Project.find(function (err, projects) {
        projects.forEach( function( project ){
            res.json(project.tags);
        });
    });
});
```

and anything else i tried just returned

```
[ ]
```

or errored out...

(additionally i wonder, how can i make sure that if i add a tag to a project and its already existant how i can keep it from adding.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call `find` on the schema, when you should be trying to call it on a model.

If you change the bottom of your file to:

```
var TagModel     = mongoose.model( 'TagModel', TagSchema );
var ProjectModel = mongoose.model( 'ProjectModel', Project );
```

and then in your `app.get` function calls:

```
app.get('/tags.json', function(req, res) {
    TagModel.find({}, function ( err, tags ){ //changed this to the model instead of the schema
        var json = JSON.stringify(tags);
        console.log(json);
    tags = tags.map(function (tag) {
        return tag.toObject();
    });
    console.log(json == JSON.stringify(tags));
    res.json(json);
    });
});
```

and

```
app.get('/tags.json', function(req, res) {
    ProjectModel.find(function (err, projects) {
        projects.forEach( function( project ){
            res.json(project.tags);
        });
    });
});
```

Models are constructors compiled from your schema definitions and represent the documents that can be saved and queried from the db.

Comment: having defined everything like you said helped me out a bit, as the second code finally shows the tags in json, but i found out that it is only returning the tags from the lastly edited project and not all the tags that exist.

actually if i add

    console.log(JSON.stringify(project.tags));

it shows all of them in the console.

Comment: adding 
`var taglist = [];` in there
and
`taglist.push(project.tags);`
into the foreach does the trick if i render the taglist array in json!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `TagSchema` in its own model and embedded in `ProjectSchema` like you are, it's important to understand that the docs in the `tags` collection and the docs in the `tags` array of project docs have no inherent connection.  So if you save tags as part of a project, those won't end up in the `tags` collection unless you explicitly add them to that as well.

A few specific problems in your posted code:

1. You need to define `TagSchema` before you use it in `ProjectSchema`.
2. You should be passing `ProjectSchema` into the `mongoose.model` call, not `Project`.
3. Keep your schema and model names separate as it's not clear what's what in your code.

Comment: yeah i think i basicly just found out that there is a difference between schemas and models due to you guys help, thank you! i will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of @alawson421's code and some array magic it works perfectly, thanks again @JohnnyHK for showing me the difference between a schema and a model. heres the working fix:

```
app.get('/tags.json', function(req, res) {
    ProjectModel.find(function (err, projects) {
        var taglist = [];

        projects.forEach( function( project ){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(project.tags));
            project.tags.forEach( function( tag ){
                console.log(tag);
                taglist.push(tag.name);
            }); 
        });

        res.json(taglist);
    });
});
```

and the output is:

```
[
    "test",
    "meep",
    "lalela",
    "another test",
    "ihopethisworks",
    "noderocks",
    "i am not a mongo",
    "ice cream rocks"
]
```